# Sorting a table according to date columns in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a table with 2 columns; `insdate` and `resdate`.These include date data. I want to sort according to column. For example if the user clicks `resdate` column I want to be able to sort it in increasing/decreasing order.

I tried to do something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6H1DfXjMn0).

My data is returned as a json data from webservice. And **dates are returned as string**.
Something like this is returned from the server side:

```
  logs = [
        { insdate: '11.12.2018 06:41:25', resdate: '11.12.2018 06:41:26' },
        { insdate: '10.12.2018 06:42:24 ', resdate: '10.12.2018 06:42:24' },
        { insdate: '10.12.2018 06:42:29', resdate: '10.12.2018 06:42:29'},
        { insdate: '12.12.2018 06:45:00', resdate: '12.12.2018 06:45:00' },
        { insdate: '11.12.2018 06:45:47', resdate: '11.12.2018 06:45:47' },
        { insdate: '10.12.2018 06:46:42', resdate: '10.12.2018 06:46:42' },
        { insdate: '10.12.2018 06:46:42', resdate: '' },
        { insdate: '', resdate: '12.12.2018 07:16:50' },
    ];
```

My dates are in `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss` format. And the results returned are ordered by `insdate` in server side. Also notice that `insdate` or `resdate` might be empty.

For the table I have

```
<th (click)="sortType('resdate')" [class.active]="sortBy==='resdate' ">ResDate</th>
```

in my app.component.html.

And finally in my app.component.ts file I have:

```
sortType(sort: string)
  {
    this.copyLogs=this.logs;
    if(sort==='resdate'){
      this.logs=this.copyLogs.sort(this.sortByResDate);
    }   
  }

 sortByResDate(r1: any, r2:any){
   let d1=moment(r1.resdate, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss').unix();
   let d2 = moment(r2.resdate, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss').unix();

    if(d1>d2) {
      return 1;
    }
    else if(d1===d2) {
      return 0;
    }
    else return -1; 
  }
```

Since my dates were type string, I tried using unix time for comparison. But something is wrong because my dates are not correctly sorted. The functions are accessed, sorting is working but not correctly :).

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

I did it without `moment()`. Just using `new date ()` and `getTime()`. Everything works well. You only need to determine where you want to see an empty resdate at the beginning of the table or at the end.

### Update

Previous solution didn't work correctly with format `dd:mm:yyyy HH:mm:ss`.
New solution with `moment()`:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x3vdpq
P.S. If you have some problems with `import moment` try to add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` and then use the syntax:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Comment: At first I also did it with new Date() but the problem was if the date was for example: 13.12.2018 02:44 then it was seen as invalid date because I think it was detecting format as MM.dd.yyyy. because when I changed 13 to 10 it was not invalid date, it was saying the date is 12th of October which is not correct because my date format is dd.MM it should have been 10th of December. That is why I formatted it with momentjs

Comment: By the way I think the format in the moment should be DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss.  moment(r1.resdate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss'). Not with lowercase dd and yyyy. It is defined liked this in momentjs docs. I changed it to correct version but mine is still working wrong :)